# CSS word-wrap is not working in Chrome

Tags: css

I have got this css code

```
    margin:100px 30px 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 250px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
```

But when my div's text is too long it is not going into new line automatically.

Comment: that CSS code is invalid, you are missing the units

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. Also, your font and margin should include a unit.

Comment: @dippas is it necessary?Because it is working without it

Comment: For me, the reason "word-wrap: break-word;" was not working, was that I had it as a "flex" child. If I set the width specifically, "word-wrap: break-word;" worked as expected. Very oddly, "word-**break**: break-word;" works in both cases. (so I just use that instead -- which is sad, though, since it's not as standard)

Answer (score 2):

Your code works i think there is an other problem did you not overwrite it some where else in your css?

```css
div{
 margin:10px 30px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 250px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    word-break: break-word; /*word-wrap: break-word;*/
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div>
<p>
reomndnsvnunqjnvnbnvdfnsbnsnbnisnbninbinnbnfknbindfibnfnbinqsibninfinibnsdinisndinbisnfdiobnisnbinsi
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No.Even in DT it shows only one css for this element

Comment: No it is not online.But btw i have got several div's with this class.Can that be problem?

Comment: I dont know it can but time I not see the code I can not tell you what is the problem but try to change the class name already

Comment: I changed it is still same